# Inconsistent Workflow behavior for Outbound Messages

Tags: workflow, workflowoutboundmessage

I have a workflow rule with Evaluation Criteria - **Evaluate the rule when a record is created, and every time it's edited** and Rule Criteria - **TRUE**.

This workflow is supposed to sends a Outbound Message to an specific endpoint whenever a Contact record is created or updated.

When I update the Contact record, the Outbound Message appears in **Outbound Messaging Delivery Status**, but when I again update it or another Contact record or if I create a new one, the Outbound Messages are not getting generated.
However, the debug logs shows that the workflow executed successfully.

The behavior is inconsistent.
Can anyone please let me know what might be the issue here.

P.S. I am performing above operations as **Sys Admin** and I have **Send Outbound Messages** permission enabled on my Profile.

Comment: Are you sure they're not being generated? Once successfully delivered, I believe they're removed from the list. Also, the system "debounces" the list, so if a given outbound message for a given contact is already queued, it won't generate a second one. This prevents flooding from multiple edits in short succession.

Comment: Since, I am not able to see them under Outbound Messaging Delivery Status, I am assuming they are not generated. Because, I can see them foe some updates, but not for all.